# What does this x = y == 1 type of declaration mean in python?

Tags: python

I got a code online and it has a statement similar to x = y == 1. Could anyone tell me what does this mean, it would help me understand the whole program.

Comment: This is the same as `x = (y == 1)`.

Comment: It sets `x` to the result of the comparison `y == 1`…

Comment: `y == 1` gets evaluated to either True or False

Comment: There is no need to downvote this question, it's a beginner question and we **all** have been a beginner

Comment: @Cid Yeah, but: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/476)

Comment: @deceze I know right, but typing this declaration in Google doesn't provide any useful link. And it's way better than the usual copy/paste of homework assignment or unclear and broad questions. It's not a great question, but, IMO, it's not a bad one neither

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python it should mean x = (y==1)
So if y is equal to one value of x will become true and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

y == 1 is a logical operator, meaning -> is value of a declared variable y equal to 1? response is true or false, so the boolean (false or true) value is assigned to the x variable.

more on operators here. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you have a condition that is basically like this though:

```
if <condition>:
    var = True
else:
    var = False
```

then it is much easier to simply assign the result of the condition directly:

```
var = <condition>
```

In your case, **x** is the **var** and **y == 1** is the **condition**:

```
x = y == 1
```